# Is there a vectorized way to find overlap in intervals between 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have 2 dataframes: `df1, df2`.
e.g.,

```
df1:

id   start   end
1    0       15
1    15      30
1    30      45
2    0       15
2    15      30
2    30      45

df2 = 
id   start   end   
1    0       1.1    
1    1.1     11.4  
1    11.4    34    
1    34      46    
2    0       1.5   
2    1.5     20   
2    20      30
```

For each row in `df1`, I want to find the rows in `df2` such that `df1.id == df2.id` and there is overlap between the 2 intervals `[df1.start, df1.end]` and `[df2.start, df2.end]`. The overlap is defined by the condition: `df1.start <= df2.end AND df1.end > df2.start)`

So for the above, the result should be

```
[0, 1, 2]
[2]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[5, 6]
[6]
```

Is there a vectorized way to do this?

The output should be a dataframe (or some other structure) that has length `len(df1)` where each row are the indices in `df2` that fit the aforementioned constraints. `df2` is quite large, on the order of millions, and `df1` is on the order of 10s of the thousands, so there may be memory concerns. Technically, I only need 1 row at a time to process before moving on to the next row, so I don't necessarily need to store all the rows, but that may ruin the vectorization if I process a row at a time?

Ultimately, I want to use the output indices to compute weight averages. `df2` has a 4th column, `quantity`, and I want to compute its weighted average where the weights are proportional to the amount of overlap. So technically I don't need to store the overlap indices, but I think the memory problem would still persist since they will stilled by stored implicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross merge on `id`, `query` the rows of interest, then `groupby`:

```
(df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on='id', suffixes=['','_x'])
    .query('start < end_x & end > start_x')
    .groupby(['index'])['index_x'].agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
index
0    [0, 1, 2]
1          [2]
2       [2, 3]
3       [4, 5]
4       [5, 6]
Name: index_x, dtype: object
```

**Note**: your data size would be a problem for a cross merge. In which case, maybe working with different `id` in `df1` would be much better. Then you can resolve to multithread.

```
data = []
# isolate data:
for ID, d in df1.groupby('id'):
    overlaps = (d.reset_index().merge(df2.query('id == @ID').reset_index(),
                                      on='id', suffixes=['','_x'])
                 .query('start < end_x & end > start_x')
                 .groupby(['index'])['index_x'].agg(list)
               )
    data.append(overlaps)

pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
index
0    [0, 1, 2]
1          [2]
2       [2, 3]
3       [4, 5]
4       [5, 6]
Name: index_x, dtype: object
```

---

Update per comment:

```
(df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='id', suffixes=['','_x'])
    .assign(overlap=lambda x: x[['end','end_x']].min(axis=1) - x[['start','start_x']].max(axis=1))
    .query('overlap > 0')
    .groupby('index')['overlap'].mean()
)
```

Output:

```
index
0     5.0
1    15.0
2     7.5
3     7.5
4     7.5
Name: overlap, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in the OP, and I'm not sure if this'll simplify things, but ultimately, I want to use output to compute weight averages. `df2` has a 4th column, `quantity`, and I want to compute its weighted average where the weights are proportional to the amount of overlap. So technicaly I don't need to store the overlap indices, but I think the memory problem would still persist since they will stilled by stored implicitly?

Comment: The overlap amount is `min(end_x, end) - max(start_x, start)`. You can compute that first, then query that `>=0` instead of the current query. Then `groupby('index').mean()`, and you got the average of overlap per row.

Comment: ah I see, but you'd need to compute an overlap matrix that's `len(df1) x len(df2)`?

Comment: And do you mind including your comment as part of your answer? I'll edit the OP to reflect the ultimate purpose

Comment: Why's the output only 5 rows btw? `df1` has 6 rows

Comment: Oh I see why. It seems to not include the row that has an empty list of indices or a zero weighted average. I think I need to include that in my codebase

Comment: If I also want to include the empty indices or zero weighted average, I know I can just change the query to `.query('overlap >= 0')`, but this will do some unnecessary calculations when `overlap==0`. Do you think this is the best approach?